# Percentage widths in nested flexbox adds unexpected space

Tags: css, flexbox, percentage

I noticed a weird bug in all the major browsers when you use a percentage width on an element in a nested flexbox with its `justify-content` property set to "flex-end". It renders the parent element as if the child were set to 100% width regardless of the percentage actually used by the child.

I have created a Fiddle to demonstrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/u21pe916/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-col-1">Column 1</div>

  <div class="flex-col-2">
    <div class="nested-col-1" id="percent-width">Nested Column 1</div>
    <div class="nested-col-2">Nested Column 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-col-1">Column 1</div>

  <div class="flex-col-2">
    <div class="nested-col-1" id="unit-width">Nested Column 1</div>
    <div class="nested-col-2">Nested Column 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-col-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nested-col-1 {
  /* Overflow is for display purposes. It does not affect the bug. */
  overflow: hidden;
}

#percent-width {
  width: 0%;
}

#unit-width {
  width: 0px;
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot of flexbox bug]

Is there a fix/work-around so that percentage values can be used without creating the extra space?

Comment: I suspect that's why we don't use width in flexbox...we use flex-basis. I'm not entirely clear on what it is you are trying to do though.

Comment: I'm using width instead of flex-basis, because I need to transition the width of an element. Support for CSS transitions of flex-basis aren't good with the current browsers.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you are trying to do though..

Comment: I have an element with a 0% width that will transition to 100% width on hover. However, because of this bug, the parent container is always leaving empty space as if the element is already at 100% width.

Comment: Guess that flexbox isn't for you then. I confess I'm not that deep into the spec but I do know that `overflow` is kinda different in flexbox - https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins